# Can Entity Translate work on the node body?

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

**Problem**

I'm using Entity Translate for the multi-lingual parts of my site, this allows me to use the language switcher. (I've enabled it for content, and then on the content type I've enabled field translation).

However the node body is not translatable.

Do I need to create a field and use that as the body, or have I set-up entity translation badly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah turns out you have to enable translation for the field once you've enabled translation for the content type.

Open up your content type, edit the field you want to make translatable then head down to the bottom of the page.

You should see something like:

**Field translation**
Users may translate all occurrences of this field:

- *Body in Basic page*
- *Body in Article*
- *Body in Webform*
- *Body in Test Content*
- *Body in Upgrade & Search Token Product Display*
- *Body in Blog post/Article*
- *Body in Development Blog*

Click on "Enable translation" and you're good to go.

Comment: What's that link in your answer?

Comment: Just some random letters, in Drupal it's an admin path, but it looks like a link. So to give it formatting to match the real one I just added a random link. Hmm perhaps that's confusing.

Comment: Totally, remove it please.

Comment: Cheers for that!